# Multiple tabs with Jquery in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabs

I have a table named description, I want to show all descriptions related to one item, when I print the descriptions on this way, it shows me all descriptions

```
<?php        
    foreach($multimedia->descriptions as $description ){                    
        echo "<br>";
        echo __('Title: ');
        print_r ($description->titleDescription);
        echo "<br>";
        echo __('Description: ');
        print_r ($description->descriptionDescription);    
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }                
?>
```

But when I try to show the same on diferent tabs only show me the last description:

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><?= ($description->titleDescription);?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p><?= ($description->titleDescription);?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i show each description on different tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop on every description:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php 
            foreach($multimedia->descriptions as $key => $description) {
                echo '<li><a href="#tabs-'.$key.'">'
                    .$$description->titleDescription
                .'</a></li>'; 
            } 
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
        foreach($multimedia->descriptions as $key => $description) {
    ?>
    <div id="tabs-<?= $key ; ?>">
        <p><?= ($description->titleDescription);?></p>
    </div>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i did that, the titles shows well but the description no, all descriptions appear on every tab not only those related to the title